# Script fires every time I change fields in Formik form on a React site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, formik

I have a `<script>` that I am embedding in a Formik form on a React site. The script grabs an ID from Jornaya and puts it into a hidden field for submitting.
The script works great and the hidden field is populated as expected ... at first.

The problem is this. Every time I select a new field, or change the data in any field, the script fires and fetches another ID plus I'm creating a ton of XHR requests. When I submit, the field is blank (as it hasn't received its new value yet).

Here is the function I'm calling

```js
       export function leadId() {
         const s = document.createElement("script")
         s.id = "LeadiDscript_campaign"
         s.type = "text/javascript"
         s.async = true
         s.src =
           "//create.lidstatic.com/campaign/7d5a73f4-d32d-c39a-6745-b920c70d0d53.js?snippet_version=2"
    
         document.head.appendChild(s)
    }
```

My plain ol Field element

```js
    <Field type="hidden" id="leadid_token" name="sr_token" value="" />
```

EDIT*** My function call ***

I'm calling the leadId() from the page that contains the form

```js
export default class GetStartedPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    leadId()

    return (
      <StyledPage>
        <MyForm ...
```

*** end edit ***

Here's a demo of my problem. Where the sr_token field is changing on every change.

[image: Demo of problem]

TIA!

Comment: How are you implementing the `leadId()` function? Can you provide the snippet?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I've added the snippet into the question. Just to answer your question. I'm calling the script from the page that my component lives in.

Comment: Possible issue: append the script to the body, not head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is calling `leadId()` in the render method. Try moving it to a hook or effect that's called once when the component mounts.

Quibble: per Jornaya documentation, append the script to the `body`, not the `head`. https://docs.jornaya.com/v1/docs/en/web-form-create-implementation